# Performance of removing multiple items from the head of a SortedMap

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, sortedmap, concurrentskiplistmap

I'm working in Java and have a SortedMap, which is implemented as a ConcurrentSkipListMap. I need to remove a number of items from the head of the SortedMap - i.e., all items whose key is less than some threshold. The number of items actually removed may end up being 0, 1, or multiple. It is possible, but rather unlikely, that this will cause all items in the entire SortedMap to be removed (i.e., it's extremely likely at least one item will be larger than the threshold, though it's not guaranteed).

It seems to me that there should be a way to do this rather efficiently since we can take advantage of the assumptions that 1) the items to be removed are consecutive, and 2) the first item to be removed is the head of the SortedMap (and per #1, the rest follow consecutively thereafter). If I build my own skip list this is very easy to do, but I'm lazy and don't want to rebuild all the logic already provided for me in the built-in ConcurrentSkipListMap just to have this one custom operation. So my question is, how can I take advantage of those assumptions for performance while using the ConcurrentSkipListMap?

I've come up with the following methods, but don't know if they're really taking advantage of my assumptions:

```
SortedMap<Date, Item> mymap = ConcurrentSkipListMap<Date, Item>();
addItemsToMap(mymap);
Date threshold = calculateThreshold();
```

Method 1:
Iterate through, removing items until I reach the threshold.

```
Iterator<Entry<Date, Item>> itr = mymap.entrySet().iterator();
for (Date key = itr.next().getKey(); key.before(threshold); key = itr.next().getKey())
    itr.remove();
```

Method 2:
Repeatedly remove the first item, until the first item exceeds the threshold.

```
for (Date key = mymap.firstKey(); key.before(threshold); key = mymap.firstKey())
    mymap.remove(key);
```

Method 3:
Get the set of entries from the head to the threshold, then remove all of them.

```
Iterator<Entry<Date, Item>> itr2 = mymap.headMap(threshold).entrySet().iterator();
while (itr2.hasNext()) {
    itr2.next();
    itr2.remove();
}
```

Method 4:
More elegant version of #3.

```
mymap.headMap(threshold).clear();
```

Comment: You're not going to get more efficient than #4.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Well, I don't think that's exactly the case. Let `N` be the number of items in the SortedMap and `M` the number of items to be removed (s.t. m <= n). Then method 4 is _at best_ `O(log(N) + M)` time. It may be worse if clear() removes the items one-by-one instead of all simultaneously (as there may be bookkeeping overhead for the skip list parts after each removal). Still it's probably less bookkeeping overhead than a tree-based SortedMap (I _think_). Ideally, I'd like to be able to remove the first `M` items in `O(M)` time.

Comment: That said, for now I've done #4 because it's the simplest and easiest to understand, and I'll change it only if and when I see performance being a problem.

Comment: I don't buy that method 4 is at best `O(log N + M)` time.  `headMap` returns a _view_, which means that it can return in constant time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oops, you're right. I looked at the code some, and Method 4 is actually pretty equivalent to Method 2. Furthermore, I _assume_ the complexity of getting an iterator at the head of the list is the same as the findFirst() method (the same logic must be applied, or else how would the iterator correctly know where to start, right?) In that case, the only real difference between Method 1 and 2 & 4 is the difference between `iterator.remove()` and `map.remove(key)` ... The code for remove was harder to follow with the different hierarchy levels, but it's doubtful there's a difference

Comment: Indeed.  There's probably not a difference, and #4 is clearest.  (Additionally, #4 is the one that the JDK maintainers could optimize for you in the future.)

Comment: Then there's Method 3... the complexity of this all depends on whether calling entrySet() on a view is still just a view, or if it has to realize the set (make it concrete) in order to do that. In any case, it is _at best_ the same complexity of the others...  So where that leaves us is - Methods 1, 2, and 4 all have the same complexity, which is `O(M * r)` where `r` is the time to remove a single item. This could be reduced to `O(M + r)` if all items could be removed together instead of iteratively, but no way to do that exists. However, if `r` is constant time then it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's a good point about future optimization... (In my case this code probably won't survive until Java 8 anyway, but in the general case it may matter.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the `tailMap` method provided in the `ConcurrentSkipListMap` class.

Since this `Collection` is sorted you might have to pass the `key` to the method from which you need the the data.

You can have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#tailMap%28K%29).

For example - Let us assume my `ConcurrentSkipListMap` has keys `1,2,4,5` and my threshold is 2. I would pass `2 + 1 = 3` to the `tailMap` method and I would get back a `ConcurrentNavigableMap` with `4` and `5` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to remove the smallest several items, though, not the largest. So in your example, `1, 2` perhaps... So instead of tailMap() I can use headMap(), which I did in methods 3 and 4 above.